# How to install sl4a from the new website?

Tags: android, sl4a

I am wanting to install sl4a on my android for a project that I am working on but I can't seem to figure out where the apk is. I understand that there used to be a google project site and the apk was on the homepage, but after the site moving to a new location, they moved the apk and I don't know where.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now I have posted apks in github. and another works in progress on it.
https://github.com/kuri65536/sl4a/releases

Comment: So i guess i would download the "sl4a-r6.1.1-arm-debug.apk" and install it on my android?

Comment: I downloaded it and installed it. I am using Script Launcher to run a python script that has to be able to write to a .txt file. To do that I needed more rights. So by installing SL4A and running it from there i had sufficient rights. But then I get an error every time i try and run the script. 

Also, what is an arm device?

Comment: 'arm device' means that your CPU is arm. What error did you receive? or waht is 'rights'? BTW, I tested sl4a with android 5.1 rooted device. please tell me more information and your sample code to be failed.

Answer (score 0):

sl4a-r6.2.0-arm7-debug.apk and rhino-r6.1.1-debug.apk (javascript) from https://github.com/kuri65536/sl4a releases

jan, 2024
I downloaded it and installed it on my android 11, got messages was made for an older version of android.  The text is so small when to run the demo hello_world.js in the console I had to use screenshot and google photos to see this result:  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.android.internal.util.WithFramework

Process has exited.

The following website appears to have the source code(sl4a) for newer versions of android but I cannot locate any *.apk files.
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/sl4a/+refs